# Jenkins Maven POM Version number not changing

Tags: maven, github, jenkins, pom.xml, snapshot

I have a simple Maven project that I am using as a Sandbox project to investigate how to push variables from Jenkins into a Maven build so they appear in the artifacts. (Or better still have Jenkins add parameters to the Maven build and leave the original intact).

I have been fiddling with the POM file version number to see how it affects the snapshot artifacts POM.

When I have changed it in the original POM file the version number does not change in the Artifact POM.

I thought the POM.xml is where the version number came from.

Does Jenkins create the snapshot version number?

Any ideas where the version number  1.0-SNAPSHOT is coming from when version 1.2 is in the POM.xml?

Comment: Please share the relevant portions of your pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your pom file has below lines , if yes then change it false and see if that helps

`<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>`

Comment: Thanks prudviraj, would never have found that, It was hidden away at the bottom. I've only started using Jenkins recently so I'm still finding my feet. THL